# Plot recipes - what is exactly the difference between the different options

Tags: plot, julia

I have now already reading quite a lot about recipes in the `Plots.jl` Package, but still do not get the differences completely: as far as I understand a type recipe is to define special plotting behaviours for a type and with an user recipe you define your own plot behaviours.

My question is now, could these two concepts come hand in hand: lets imagine that I have an user recipe:

```
@userplot foo
@recipe function f(h::foo)
     do some stuff
end
```

and now I could use this as `foo(x)` and my plot will be created.

A type recipe is:

```
type myfoo
   ...
end

@recipe function f(x::myfoo)
    do some stuff
end
```

and the plot is created with `plot(y::myfoo)`.

Could I somehow define the userplot to use the plot definition of the type recipe or vice versa?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@userplot` recipes serve to define general plot recipes that work across different types. For example, you can define the recipe of `histogram` for pretty much any type of ordered data.

On the other hand, the type recipes are natural when your type has a visual representation. For example, if your type is the `Histogram` itself, then it makes sense to define the recipe for the type and plot it as `plot(hist)` with `hist` an instance of `Histogram`.

This is how I decide between these two concepts in my own packages, it is a personal choice. You are completely free to call one recipe inside of the other. I don't see a clear motivation for having two recipes outputting the same plot though.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. My thinking about calling on recipe from the other was to allow users having a own data type for doing some plots but still also having just a special plot command, where they could put any data inside the like.